# Temporary Storage for Decrypted Database on Android

Tags: java, android, database, encryption

I have been working on a pet project of mine that relies on a SQLite database to store information.  Recently, I have decided that I want the application to be password protected and for the database to be encrypted.  So far, no major problems.  In my design I have been trying to focus on the maximum possible security.  Yes, I know that the greatest security is fairly worthless considering that everything (I am talking salts and cypher text; password is in the user's brain) is stored on one device and anyone who knows what they are doing can likely break it if they possess the device.  So why bother?  Because I can.

So, to this end I have been contemplating where to store the decrypted version of my database while the application is running.  The most common suggestion online for temporary storage is to the the SD card.  This doesn't sit well with me as the data on the SD card will persist if the application abnormally terminates (enter the over-zealous user with a task manager) or is never terminated at all.

Lately I have been toying with the idea of storing the entire thing in memory, but this seems like very bad practice.  The database on my test device is absolutely tiny (less than 100K with a mountain of test data in it) but it still rubs me the wrong way that is it possible for a user to have a large database in the wild.  I am very well aware of the fact that as soon as anyone says "the user will never do / have that", some guy will beat that limitation into the ground.

So, posed in question form: where is the best place on an Android device to temporarily store a decrypted database?  Preferably somewhere volatile between application executions but, at this point, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're using sqlite and the standard Android SQLite database helpers, the database must reside in /data/data//databases.  Thats the only spot the default classes will read it from.

Alternatively, you can store it on the SDCard and write a custom database helper. As you mentioned, there are obvious reasons not to do this if your data is secure.

I think i would suggest doing something in code to obfuscate your database, perhaps by shipping the database with data that requires a decoding function to interpret. Beyond that, i think a remote database would be the only viable mechanism for protecting your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Currently, I have created my own custom database helper class so that isn't an issue.  I am also doing all of the database encryption and decryption using AES from the phone's local data partition.  My question is more of just where to put the temporarily decrypted database until it is time to re-encrypt it and store it back to the file system.  A remote database has always been an attractive option, but is currently unfeasible.

Comment: @phobos51594 I'm trying hard to encrypt database file on sdcard and then decrypt it back but I fail. Could you maybe provide me with some sample code, how did you achieve this? I'd greatly appreciate this